# Batch sequential data with tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Let's consider a toy dataset, ordered, with two features:

- `value` (e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555`)
- `sequence_id` (e.g. `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1`)

This data basically consists of two flattened sequences concatenated, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` (sequence `0`), and `111, 222, 333, 444, 555` (sequence `1`).

I would like to generate sequences of size `t` (say `3`) consisting of consecutive elements from the same sequence (`sequence_id`), I do not want a sequence to have elements belonging to different `sequence_id`.

For instance, without any shuffling, I would like to get the following batches:

- 1st batch: `1, 2, 3`,
- 2nd batch: `2, 3, 4`,
- 3rd batch: `3, 4, 5`,
- 4th batch: `111, 222, 333`,
- 5th batch: `222, 333, 444`,
- 6th batch: `333, 444, 555`,
- 7th batch: `1, 2, 3`,
- etc.

I know how to generate sequence data using `tf.data.Dataset.window` or `tf.data.Dataset.batch`, but I do not know how to prevent a sequence from containing a mix of different `sequence_id` (e.g. the sequence `4, 5, 111` should not be valid as it mixes elements from sequence `0` and sequence `1`).

Below is my failed attempt:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555], 
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))\
                .window(3, 1, drop_remainder=True)\
                .repeat(-1)\
                .flat_map(lambda x, y: x.batch(3))\
                .batch(10)
data_it = data.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = data_it.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(data_it.initializer)
    print(sess.run(next_element))
```

that outputs:

```
[[  1   2   3]   # good
 [  2   3   4]   # good
 [  3   4   5]   # good
 [  4   5 111]   # bad – mix of sequence 0 (4, 5) and sequence 1 (111)
 [  5 111 222]   # bad
 [111 222 333]   # good
 [222 333 444]   # good
 [333 444 555]   # good
 [  1   2   3]   # good
 [  2   3   4]]  # good
```

Comment: Is it feasible to separate them into different arrays?

Comment: Not in this case, this case is specifically about differentiating the sequences based on some feature (here `sequence_id`). I have asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110489/batch-sequential-data-coming-from-multiple-tfrecord-files-with-tf-data)  where the different sequences are split in different TFRecord files, this might be closer to what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to judge if the `sequence_id` is consistent. Because `filter()` transformation does not currently support nested datasets as inputs, so you need `zip()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))\
                .window(3, 1, drop_remainder=True) \
                .flat_map(lambda x, y: tf.data.Dataset.zip((x,y)).batch(3))\
                .filter(lambda x,y: tf.equal(tf.size(tf.unique(y)[0]),1))\
                .map(lambda x,y:x)\
                .repeat(-1)\
                .batch(10)
data_it = data.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = data_it.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(data_it.initializer)
    print(sess.run(next_element))

[[  1   2   3]
 [  2   3   4]
 [  3   4   5]
 [111 222 333]
 [222 333 444]
 [333 444 555]
 [  1   2   3]
 [  2   3   4]
 [  3   4   5]
 [111 222 333]]
```