# Batch sequential data coming from multiple TFRecord files with tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Let's consider a dataset split into multiple TFRecord files:

- `1.tfrecord`,
- `2.tfrecord`,
- etc.

I would like to generate sequences of size `t` (say `3`) consisting of consecutive elements from the same TFRecord file, I do not want a sequence to have elements belonging to different TFRecord files.

For instance, if we have two TFRecord files containing data like:

- `1.tfrecord`: `{0, 1, 2, ..., 7}`
- `2.tfrecord`: `{1000, 1001, 1002, ..., 1007}`

without any shuffling, I would like to get the following batches:

- 1st batch: `0, 1, 2`,
- 2nd batch: `1, 2, 3`,
- ...
- i-th batch: `5, 6, 7`,
- (i+1)-th batch: `1000, 1001, 1002`,
- (i+2)-th batch: `1001, 1002, 1003`,
- ...
- j-th batch: `1005, 1006, 1007`,
- (j+1)-th batch: `0, 1, 2`,
- etc.

I know how to generate sequence data using `tf.data.Dataset.window` or `tf.data.Dataset.batch`, but I do not know how to prevent a sequence from containing element from different files.

I'm looking for a scalable solutions, i.e. the solution should work with hundred of TFRecord files.

Below is my failed attempt (fully reproducible example):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# ****************************
# Generate toy TF Record files

def _create_example(i):
    example = tf.train.Features(feature={'data': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[i]))})
    return tf.train.Example(features=example)

def parse_fn(serialized_example):
    return tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, {'data': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)})['data']


num_tf_records = 2
records_per_file = 8
options = tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions(tf.python_io.TFRecordCompressionType.GZIP)
for i in range(num_tf_records):
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('%i.tfrecord' % i, options=options) as writer:
        for j in range(records_per_file):
            example = _create_example(j + 1000 * i)
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
# ****************************
# ****************************


data = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['0.tfrecord', '1.tfrecord'], compression_type='GZIP')\
            .map(lambda x: parse_fn(x))

data = data.window(3, 1, 1, True)\
           .repeat(-1)\
           .flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(3))\
           .batch(16)

data_it = data.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = data_it.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(data_it.initializer)
    print(sess.run(next_element))
```

which outputs:

```
[[   0    1    2]   # good
 [   1    2    3]   # good
 [   2    3    4]   # good
 [   3    4    5]   # good
 [   4    5    6]   # good
 [   5    6    7]   # good
 [   6    7 1000]   # bad – mix of elements from 0.tfrecord and 1.tfrecord
 [   7 1000 1001]   # bad
 [1000 1001 1002]   # good
 [1001 1002 1003]   # good
 [1002 1003 1004]   # good
 [1003 1004 1005]   # good
 [1004 1005 1006]   # good
 [1005 1006 1007]   # good
 [   0    1    2]   # good
 [   1    2    3]]  # good
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to `flat_map` that function you have to make the `windo` datasets:

```
def make_dataset_from_filename(filename):
  data = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename, compression_type='GZIP')\
           .map(lambda x: parse_fn(x))

  data = data.window(3, 1, 1, True)\
             .repeat(-1)\
             .flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(3))\
             .batch(16)

tf.data.Dataset.list_files('*.tfrecord').flat_map(make_dataset_from_filename)
```